# Most efficient way to run matching table (500 x 3) on (1m x 10) pandas dataset

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, google-analytics, apply

The problem in 1 sentence: I am currently using a pandas apply function to replicate an Excel Vlookup, however I feel like this is not the most efficient way, as it takes a long time to process (10 minutes for a dataset with 600k rows and 10-15 columns.

I have a dataset with Google Analytics data. I want to assign a specific campaignID to each unique URL in the dataset and am currently using a matching table + apply lambda function to do this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| df_ftr | Dataset with Google Analytics data |
| df_match | Matching table |
| campaignId | Unique key that is generated by our CRM system and has to be assigned to a given page |
| pagePath | URL that I use as a lookup value in the matching table |
| property | The dataset contains data from 3 different websites. This is an additional condition that needs to be satisfied in order to be able to assign a given campaignID. |

```
df_ftr['campaignId'] = df_ftr['pagePath'].progress_apply(lambda x: df_match['campaignId'][(df_match['pagePath'] == x) & (df_match['property'] == i)].values[0] if len(df_match.loc[df_match['pagePath'] == x].loc[df_match['property'] == i].values) > 0 else np.nan)
```

Snippet of Google Analytics dataset (example):

| Date | pagePath | campaignId | property | Pageviews, etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06/03/23 | / |  | 0 | 34 |
| 06/03/23 | /about-us |  | 0 | 12 |
| 06/03/23 | /about-us |  | 1 | 32 |

Snippet of Matching table (example):

| pagePath | property | campaignId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| / | 0 | POE-3732-CNS |
| /about-us | 0 | EHE-7648-FHD |
| /about-us | 1 | OWS-2739-WJS |

What is the most efficient way to approach this?

I already tried to speed up the process with pandarallel (multi core processing) and while this cuts about 25% of the total time required, it still takes too much time to run on a frequent interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little difficult to compare your solution to mine since you did not provide th function you applied, but you can check

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

df_ftr = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['06/03/23', '06/03/23', '06/03/23'],
    'pagePath': ['/', '/about-us', '/about-us'],
    'property': [0, 0, 1],
    'Pageviews': [34, 12, 32]
})
df_match = pd.DataFrame({
    'pagePath': ['/', '/about-us', '/about-us'],
    'property': [0, 0, 1],
    'campaignId': ['POE-3732-CNS', 'EHE-7648-FHD', 'OWS-2739-WJS']
})

# Original solution using apply and lambda
start_time = time.time()

i = 0 
df_ftr['campaignId'] = df_ftr['pagePath'].progress_apply(lambda x: df_match['campaignId'][(df_match['pagePath'] == x) & (df_match['property'] == i)].values[0] if len(df_match.loc[df_match['pagePath'] == x].loc[df_match['property'] == i].values) > 0 else np.nan)

print("Original solution execution time: %.4f seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))

# Solution using merge
start_time = time.time()

merged_df = pd.merge(df_ftr, df_match, on=['pagePath', 'property'], how='left')
merged_df = merged_df.drop_duplicates(subset='pagePath')
merged_df = merged_df[['pagePath', 'campaignId']]
df_ftr = pd.merge(df_ftr, merged_df, on='pagePath', how='left')

print("New solution execution time: %.4f seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

which for my solution returns

```
New solution execution time: 0.0174 seconds
```

If mine is less efficient, I'll delete it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked great with some minor modifications that are specific to my script.

Comment: from 318.5640 seconds to 0.0060! Crazy how wrong I was for using apply haha

Answer (score 1):

Given your matching table contains unique entries for combinations of pagePath and property, you could do the following:

`pd.merge(df_google_analytics, df_matching, on=['pagePath', 'property'])`